# IIS URL Rewrite based on HTTPS

Tags: iis, https, redirect

2008 R2 + IIS7.5 + URL Rewrite 2.0

Is impossible rewrite action based on https?

```
<rewrite>
   <rules>
      <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^off$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>
      <rule>
            <rule name="W:Main PC" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^$" ignoreCase="true" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="main/?target=config" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
      </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

"W:Main PC" does not work with rewrite. It's working redirect.

And 302 Object moved redirect loop

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

How can I fix it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules Run FRT and read what's wrong.

Comment: According to your description. I have tried on my side.I find it works well with rewrite W:Main PC,
and it could show the default page in main  folder, so could you please share the Contents of main folder? I doubt that the program in folder may direct the page to other place.